# Automatically checking radio button and executing ng-change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im working on an Angular app, and I'm using radio buttons to swap between two data sets.

It's working as intended, except I would like one of the radio buttons to be checked when the page loads, and I would like it's ng-change argument to execute on page load as well.

My current approach is:

```
<div ng-init="value='valOne'; myFunc(value)">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="site" value="valOne" ng-model="value" ng-change="myFunc(value)">Val One</input>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="site" value="valTwo" ng-model="value" ng-change="myFunc(value)">Val Two</input>
  </label>
</div>
```

This correctly loads my page with the first radio button checked, but I am stumped as to how I can execute myFunc() on page load as well. I have tried simply calling myFunc() inside my controller after declaration as well but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you share controller code ?

Comment: Your code should work correctly, there seems no issue in the piece of code you have provided. Can you please answer below queries.

Is your function being called when you select different radio button manually?
Is it showing any error on the browser console and which browser you are using?

Comment: Yes, the function gets called as expected when I manually change the radio buttons. No errors in the console, and I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in your controller:

```
$scope.value = 'valOne';
$scope.myFunc($scope.value);
```

This should select the right radio button because of `ng-model` and execute the function.

Comment: This is the type of solution I was looking for, but unfortunately it didn't work for me!

Comment: Could you explain why it isn't working ? maybe give us a plunker to look at

Comment: I wish I knew why! My guess is it's something to do with the function being called before it has been declared. My controller is pretty big at the moment, so I'll try get a more succinct version of my app to show.

Answer (score -1):

I'd fire my function using $timeout like below:

```
function Controller($scope, $timeout){
    ...
    $timeout(function(){
         $scope.myFunc(value);
    },1000);
}
```